# Finding bound for type 1 and type 2 error

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, exponential-distribution

Suppose that $T_1,…,T_{10}$ are iid $Exp(λ)$ and the goal is to test if $H_0:λ≤1$ versus $H_a:λ≥2$. Suppose that the test statistic is $S=\sum_{i=1}^{10}Ti$, and rejection of the null occurs when $S≤7$. Find the tighest bound for type 1 and type 2 error.

For the type 1 error, I know that the $P(Reject  \space H_0 | H_0) = P(S<7|\lambda \leq 1)$ Did I set this up correctly?

Comment: A type 1 error is the probability you reject the null given that a specific (unknown) $\lambda$ living in the parameter space of the null hypothesis, $\lambda \le 1$, is indeed the true parameter. You don’t know which value this is but can you answer at which $\lambda \le 1$ is the probability of a type 1 error greatest? Btw, the sum of iid exponential rvs has what distribution?

Comment: gamma distribution, but i am unsure how to find at which $λ≤1$ gives the greatest probability of a type 1 error.