# Finding a type 1 error

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics

Suppose that $T_1,…,T_{10}$ are iid $Exp(λ)$ and the goal is to test if $H_0:λ≤1$ versus $H_a:λ≥2$. Suppose that the test statistic is $S=\sum_{i=1}^{10}T_i$, and rejection of the null occurs when $S≤7$.

---

I realize that $T_1...T_{10}$ is a gamma distribution  of $S =Gamma(10, \lambda$),
but I am not sure how to use this information to find the p-value for the type 1 error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding bound for type 1 and type 2 error](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/517521/finding-bound-for-type-1-and-type-2-error)

Comment: No, it doesn't answer the question

Comment: Apologies, that is an artefact of flagging it as a duplicate. Please consider editing your original question, as they are quite similar as written and we prefer keeping answers for similar questions in the same page.

Comment: Do not [cross-post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4084859/321264) please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When computing the Type I error, you assume $H_0$ is true.  So you are finding the $P(S \le 7 | \lambda \le 1)$.  As $\lambda$ gets smaller, we expect $S$ to get larger, so $P(S \le 7 | \lambda \le 1)$ will be the largest when $\lambda = 1$.  $P(S \le 7 | \lambda \le 1) \le P(S \le 7 | \lambda = 1) = P(S \sim Gamma(10, 1) \le 7) = 0.1695$

One other note, the null and alternate hypothesis normally divide the parameter space without holes.  Did you mean to say $H_a: \lambda > 1$?  You can compute this in R with `pgamma(7, 10, 1)`

```r
Nsims <- 10000

lambda0 <- 1
n <- 10
S <- numeric(Nsims)
for (i in 1:Nsims) {
  Tn <- rexp(n, rate = lambda0) # lambda is E(exp(lambda)) = 1 / lambda
  S[i] <- sum(Tn)
}

hist(S, freq = FALSE)
lines(seq(0,30,length=1000), dgamma(seq(0,30,length=1000), n, lambda0))
```

[image]

```r
#P(S < 7 | lambda0 = 1)

length(which(S <= 7)) / length(S)
#> [1] 0.1723
pgamma(7, 10, 1)
#> [1] 0.1695041
```

Comment: thank you! this makes so much sense. The problem actually gives me $H_a \geq 2$, but I  agree, it normal should be $H_a >1$

Answer (score 1):

You reject when $S \le 7$ where, under $H_0; \lambda \le 1,$
$S \sim \mathsf{Gamma}(10, 1),$ so the probability of Type I Error
(rejecting $H_0$ when $H_0$ is true) is
$\alpha = P(S \le 7\, |\, H_0) = 0.1695.$ [Computation in R, where
`pgamma` is a gamma CDF.]

```
pgamma(7, 10, 1)
[1] 0.1695041
```

Then $\beta = P(x \ge 7\, |\, H_a) = 1 - P(S \le 7\, |\, H_a) =  0.109,$
whee $H_a: \lambda \ge 2.$

```
1 - pgamma(7, 10, 2)
[1] 0.1093994
```

In the figure below $\alpha$ is the area under the blue density curve to the
left of $s = 7$ and $\beta$ is the area under the brown density curve to the right
of $s=7.$

[image]

R code for figure:

```
hdr = "Density functions of GAMMA(10,1) [null, blue] and GAMMA(10,2)"
curve(dgamma(x, 10, 1), 0, 20, ylim=c(0,.3), col="blue", lwd=2,
      ylab="Density", xlab="s", main=hdr)
  curve(dgamma(x, 10, 2), add=T, col="brown", lwd=2)
  abline(v=0, col="green2");  abline(h=0, col="green2")
  abline(v=7, col="red", lwd=2, lty="dashed")
```

Comment: Small detail: The alternative hypothesis is a composite hypothesis. The computation for $\beta$ is the computation of the suppremum of $\beta$. The actual type II error might be smaller when $\lambda>2$. (But anyway the type II error was not asked)

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus: All valid points. // Seemed incomplete without type II error and graphs.